# EC2 Instance Connect equivalent of scp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I have an EC2 instance on which I don't allow ssh.

I use EC2 Instance Connect to connect to it.

What is the alternative to scp Amazon exposes when using EC2 Instance Connect rather than ssh?

Comment: You can scp through [session manager](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/07/session-manager-launches-tunneling-support-for-ssh-and-scp/).

Comment: Can't you install the Openssh client (scp is a client) on your Ec2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

**EC2 Instance Connect** uses a web connection to Guacomole running on an AWS service, which then establishes an SSH connection on your behalf. There is no `scp` component available.

As an alternative, if you can establish a connection using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html), then it can also provide [Port Forwarding](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-port-forwarding-using-aws-system-manager-sessions-manager/) that can be used for additional connections (such as `scp`).